# Not able to import getInstance in a class

Tags: android, singleton, android-volley

I have created a class My Singleton and tried to call getInstance, but it won't import it.Below is the My singleton class which I have created- [Image Link- https://postimg.cc/471L7sr0]

```
package com.example.memeshare
import android.content.Context
import com.android.volley.Request
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley

 class MySingleton {
     class MySingleton constructor(context: Context) {
         companion object {
             @Volatile
             private var INSTANCE: MySingleton? = null
             fun getInstance(context: Context) =
                 INSTANCE ?: synchronized(this) {
                     INSTANCE ?: MySingleton(context).also {
                         INSTANCE = it
                     }
                 }
         }
         private val requestQueue: RequestQueue by lazy {
             // applicationContext is key, it keeps you from leaking the
             // Activity or BroadcastReceiver if someone passes one in.
             Volley.newRequestQueue(context.applicationContext)
         }
         fun <T> addToRequestQueue(req: Request<T>) {
             requestQueue.add(req)
         }
     }
 }
`
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is being caused by nesting class. `MySingleton` class is nested or wrapped inside the same class i.e. `MySingleton` as shown below.

```
//1st class
class MySingleton {

//2nd nested class
class MySingleton constructor(context: Context) {
         companion object {
```

Solution is to use `MySingleton.MySingleton.getInstance()` to access the second class but is approach is awful.

I don't see the need for wrapping the same class, therefore ***remove the first class and remain with the inner MySingleton class***. That way you will be able to access the 2nd class companion object.